# loop for select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create loop in select box. But I want one code for different select.
I am able create for one select but I want for multiple .

for single: [with id](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/5J29g/)

I want to change this code according class or for multiple select.
My code for this:

```
<select class="foo"></select><select class="foo"></select>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elm = document.getElementByClass('foo'),
    df = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = i;
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + i));
        df.appendChild(option);
    }
    elm.appendChild(df);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, so you could do like:

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/5fLGs/)***

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
        $('<option />').val(i).html('#option ' + i).appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is

```
document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5J29g/48/

Comment: it has cross browser issues you'd better try `document.querySelectorAll(".foo");` instead of `getElementsByClassName`, which I've used in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) along with [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = i;
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + i));
        df.appendChild(option);
    }
    $('.foo').append(function () {
        return $(df).clone()
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/un7uV/)

Answer (score 1):

I just updated your jsfiddle adding this:

```
(function() {
var foos=document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
for(var j=0;j<foos.length;j++){
    var elm = foos[j],
        df = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = i;
            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("option #" + i));
            df.appendChild(option);
        }
        elm.appendChild(df);
    }  
}());
```

sample check that out, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5J29g/49/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
   // call your code create option element here with $(this).append()
});
```